# After exiting, the home folder cannot be visited?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

I ssh to a ubuntu sever, start a web project(Rails), then I can visit this project.

I close the the ssh terminal, then the project says can not find files(view pages,css files and so on).

I put the project in the home folder(/home/byht).

why?

When closing the ssh terminal, the user's folder can not be visited ?

You know, when I put the project in another folder(/usr/local), everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the command you issued via ssh was still attached to your terminal. So when you disconnected, that process got stopped. To make sure it keeps running after the disconnect, you can e.g. use the [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command -- or make sure the process is running as a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) / started as a service (e.g. `service my_job start`, see [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart)).